# Start Activity with UI updated from notification if service running

Tags: android-service, android-mediaplayer, android, android-notifications

I'm making kind-of an audio player. Currently I have a **MediaPlayer** running in the Activity itself (which I know is bad). There is a **SeekBar** on the screen which gets updated as the music plays, like so:

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {     
    public void run()
    {
        long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
        long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

        songTotalDurationLabel.setText("" + utils.millisecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
        songCurrentDurationLabel.setText("" + utils.millisecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

        int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
        songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

        if(mp.isPlaying())
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        else
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    }       
};
```

Once the **user presses the back button** or **kills it from the recent apps list**, the music stops.
Now I want the **music to run in the background**, so looking around the internet I found to run it in a **Service**, and calling `startService()` from Activity. Also I have a **notification** come up when music is playing and removed when it is paused.

I understand from a service I'll get the music to play even when app gets closed. But what I didn't understand is, if the user taps on the notification given the service is running, the activity restarts with the SeekBar at `progress = 0`.

**How do I get the UI to update the SeekBar to the correct value from the Service after the activity restarts?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! 
The solution is to get the running services using the ActivityManager and find your service like this

```
private boolean fooRunning() 
{
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    for(RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
    {
        if("com.name.packagename.foo".equals(service.service.getClassName()))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If this method returns true, bind to the service and get the current position from the MediaPlayer object

```
public void bindToService()
{
    if(fooRunning()) 
    {
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        serviceExists = true;
    }
    else
        serviceExists = false;
}

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder serviceBinder) 
    {
        bar binder = (bar) serviceBinder;
        mService = binder.getService();

        if(serviceExists)
        {
            int getProgress = mService.mp.getCurrentPosition();
            // mp is the MediaPlayer object in the service
            seekbar.setProgress(getProgress);               
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className)
    {
    }       
};
```

The Service class is like this:

```
public class foo extends Service
{
    private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    private final IBinder mBinder = new bar();

    public class bar extends Binder 
    {
        public foo getService()
        {
            return foo.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return mBinder;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone!